# How to change textfield background color on focus

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-design

I need to change textfield background color grey to white when user tap on textfiled. Focused textfield's background color should change grey to white and other un focused textfield background color stay remain grey.

i tried this

```
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: AppColors.textFieldBG,
        focusColor: AppColors.white,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: AppColors.labelText, fontSize: 16),
        contentPadding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),

        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black26),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
```

Here is text-filed code:

```
    TextField(
              focusNode: focusNode,
              onChanged: onChanged,
              controller: controller,
              maxLines: maxLines,
              onTap: onTap,
              enabled: isEnable,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: AppColors.textFieldBG,
                  focusColor: AppColors.white,
                  hintText: hintText,
                  suffixIcon: isShowSuffixIcon
                      ? InkWell(
                          onTap: onTapIcon,
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.date_range_outlined,
                            color: AppColors.labelText,
                          ),
                        )
                      : null),
            ),
```

Comment: can you please add your text field complete code

Comment: hey @nagendranag i added textfield code.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```dart
FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
Color _color = Colors.grey;
```

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  _focusNode.addListener(() {
    if(_focusNode.hasFocus){
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.white;
      });
    }
    else{
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.grey;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    fillColor: _color,
    filled: true
  ),
  focusNode: _focusNode,
),
```

Comment: I tried this. it show _focusNode.hasFocus false every time even after requesting this focus scope.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a Focus node for the TextField

Just follow along [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) documentation you will get to know more about the possibilities you can get with using the Focus Node for textFormField or textField.